# Is padding brackets objectively the best way to write C programs?

Tags: c

void Function( int, char )

versus:

void Function (int,char)

My friend keeps saying otherwise. What is objectively the best way to write brackets?

Comment: It is important for each project to stick to a consistent coding style. But it is quite irrelevant which one you pick, as long as you just stay consistent. Any minute arguing about the best coding style is a minute of your life wasted.

Comment: Not only is this primarily opinion based, it's not game development specific. Please review the [help] before asking further questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a *best* way. There is just a *preferred* way, and that changes from person to person. There are many different semantics that various programmers with bicker on about style. I have personally seen the following 3 ways in commercial code:

`void DoSomething(int,float,string);`

`void DoSomething(int, float, string);`

`void DoSomething( int, float , string );`

Although I have a preference for one of these, I can't tell someone that *my* way is best. Therefore the best advice is to write *what works best for you*, or the chosen style for a given collaborated project.

Comment: Though I *will* say that if you write the first version, you will annoy many other programmers you work with. "Space-averse" programming results in dense, hard-to-read code. Also, can you fix that extra space after the third `float`? I can't edit it since it's a single-character edit.

Comment: Oh totally. But that hasn't stopped the horrible messes of projects with that style :p

Comment: Case in point: http://hg.icculus.org/icculus/lugaru/file/97b303e79826/Source/GameTick.cpp#l7276

Comment: There's some severe tabbing issues going on there. Someone needs to learn how to use functions =P

Answer (score 1):

There is no best way, but there are some cases where one way is better than another.

- If you're working as part of a team, that team will have it's own coding style, and you should conform to that.
- If you've inherited a bunch of legacy code you may prefer to conform to the coding style already used by that legacy code.
- If you're coding something on your own you can sometimes just use whichever style you find most readable.
- If you're writing something where a pre-defined style already exists and is expected to be used (e.g a GNU utility) you'd better use that pre-defined style.

However, in a world where source code formatters exist and are common (and free) discussions or arguments over coding style seem silly.